# Using include files for parameters in jquery mobile

Tags: php, jquery, mobile, include

Greetings and Salutations fellow stackoverflow citizens...

Question: Is it redundant or does it defeat any purpose to use include files for the "data-theme" parameter in jquery mobile?

For example:

Instead of using:

```
<div data theme="c"></div>
```

Using this:

```
<div <?php include('inc/data-theme-file-path-here.php');?> ></div>
```

?

I'd much rather change this parameter in one file as opposed to everywhere else it's located from multiple files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery is client side and based on the source and the PHP is server side.  If you want to use PHP to dynamically generate the source for this case, then more power to you. It will not alter the functionality of of jQuery Mobile one bit.  Really only you can determine if it is appropriate for your application, or makes the best sense in terms of application maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a lot cleaner to attach the theme designating class to one parent object and adjust your CSS accordingly.  Then, you only have to put it one place in the generated HTML rather than lots of places.

Example:

```
<body class="themec">
<div class="theme-item"></div>
<div class="theme-item"></div>
<div class="theme-item"></div>
<div class="theme-item"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.themec .theme-item { css items here}
```

Then, if you want to change the theme designation, you just change it in one place in your HTML and that will cause all theme-items to pick up different CSS.  Inheritance in CSS styling can be a very powerful and simplifying thing if used properly.